# Matching an expression to the end of the string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a file, this file could be anything, example test.txt.

I'm trying to extract the text example.txt from www.example.com/example.txt

Here is the regex that I've came up with:

```
\\../$
\\. for to match the dot
. for any characters in between 'com' and the forward slash
/$ to march forward slash to the end of the string.
```

Is this the correct way to get the file out?

Here's the source I've been using: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

I'm also using Java for my regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will grab file out of a URL, but exclude common trailing elements like query strings (following ?) or bookmarks (following #):

```
/[^/\?#]+(?=($|\?|#))/
```

Answer (score 2):

You're best skipping regex for this and using java's built in URL parsing

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

See the `.getFile` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your regex.  Seems your understanding of regex syntax is not that right.  Using your example, what you can do is:

`^.*` string started with anything

`/` followed by a slash

`(` (start of group)

`[^/]*` followed by bunch of thing that is not slash

`)` (end of group)

`$` to the end

i.e. the regex you can try is `^.*/([^/]*)$`